# How to clear or delete my recent TextEdit.app documents list?

Tags: mojave

How to clear or delete my recent TextEdit.app documents list? I run Mojave 10.14.4

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) TextEdit Menu bar File → Open Recent → Clear Menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open TextEdit and click on File/Open Recents. At the bottom of the Open Recents menu item is an option to clear menu. Click on this and all prior menu items will be removed.

[image]